# PhpStorm - new lines (linefeed) are being removed when saving to remote server

Tags: php, phpstorm, linefeed

**Using PhpStorm 2017.1.4**

I have a MySQL query string in PHP:

```
<php

    $MySQL_Query_String = "SELECT * 
    FROM  `VISITOR` 
    WHERE  `ID` =3

    -- eventually add the date order here as well
    ORDER BY `VISITOR`.`INACTIVE` ASC, `VISITOR`.`NAME` ASC";

?>
```

I left a comment to remind myself of something with the `--` to ignore that comment.

When I run this code in the browser - then this part is not being run by MySQL:

```
ORDER BY `VISITOR`.`INACTIVE` ASC, `VISITOR`.`NAME` ASC
```

When I debug - I see that the string is being concatenated and sent like this:

```
MySQL_Query_String = "SELECT * FROM  `VISITOR` WHERE  `ID` =3 -- eventually add the date order here as well ORDER BY `VISITOR`.`INACTIVE` ASC, `VISITOR`.`NAME` ASC";
```

The line return feeds are missing.
The last line is now being ignored by MySQL.

The funny thing is - I have this exact same code in another application - using the same version of PhpStorm - and it does NOT remove the line feeds like the one mentioned here.

As far as I can tell - and I have copied both back and forth from each application - there is no difference.

I lost a number of hours debugging this.
I did not immediately see that the lines returns were being ignored.

**Why is PhpStorm removing the line feeds here?**

Comment: You're missing the `$` before the variable name. How is that working?

Comment: PhpStorm does not remove anything ... but your FTP server may adjust line ending symbols if misconfigured etc. I do see such behaviour one hosting even if I use FileZilla to upload/download. Please check what line endings do you have in this file right now. I say -- use Unix style (`\n`) if possible -- from my observations Mac/Windows line endings is when it gets broken.

Comment: There's a menu at the bottom right that controls the line break sequence. See if you have the same selection in both files.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not comment `/* like this */` so that your comments aren't dependent on line breaks?

Comment: Edited type-o thanks

Comment: Agree - /* comment */ Is probably better - lesson learned thanks

Comment: Menu at bottom right? U mean of PHPStorm editor?